# Searching for cancel tickets by ate

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to retrieve cancel requests between 2 dates. The following is the URL I am using, but it appears to return everything.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[user,status,ticket.attachedHardwareCount,ticket.attachedHardware,ticket.attachedVirtualGuestCount,ticket.attachedVirtualGuests,itemCount,items]&objectFilter={"Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["2016-07-11T00:00:00-05:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["2016-07-11T23:59:59-05:00"]}]}}}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this request:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectFilter={"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["6/28/2016 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["6/28/2016 23:59:59"]}]}}
```

The format of the date is mm/dd/YY

And by the way you cannot specify the timezone in the request

Regards